# Get NSDate from JSON?

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json, openweathermap

I am working with Openweather API and trying to parse date property from JSON. This is date format: "dt" - Time of data calculation, unix, UTC. I have Forecast struct and there i've `var date: NSDate`. In `weatherManager.swift` i am working with SwiftyJSON and i tried with `let date = json["dt"].double` and other extension but it won't work.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date inside the API response is Unix timestamp, that means that you have to convert it to `NSDate` object. Since the unix time timestamp is number of seconds (in OpenWeather API) elapsed from 1. January 1970, we can use `NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:)` method to convert it to `NSDate` object that you need.

```
let dateUnix = json["dt"].double
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: dateUnix)
```

`date` object is now `NSDate` that you need.